# Automatically delete all files in folder that gets over 10GB?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a small server from DigitalOcean ($5/Month) and I only have about 16GB out of my 20GB on that server. I'll be hosting a site that will auto download some small files (3-6Mb) and eventually the download folder will get big. Is there some kind of cron job or script that will automatically run every day and check a specific folder, and if that folder exceeds X amount of GB, then it will attempt to clean the folder? (some files might be in use)

I'm running Ubuntu 15 if that matters. Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written a script which will do this below - please double check you are happy with it, particularly the rm -r command, as I have not executed it.  (This command should delete everything in the given folder, including subfolders.

```
#! /bin/bash

FOLDER=/folder/to/delete

MAXSIZEINGIGS=10

#### No User Serviceable Parts below this line ###

MAXSIZE=$(( $MAXSIZEINGIGS * 1024 * 1024 ))
FOLDERSIZE=`du -ks $FOLDER | cut -f1`

if [ $FOLDERSIZE -gt $MAXSIZE ]
then
        rm -r $FOLDER/*
fi
```

Create a file with the above script, then make it executable (chmod 755 filename) and add it to crontab with a line like

```
02 02 * * *    ownername   /path/to/file
```

(This will run every morning at 02:02 am, and assumes you have added it to /etc/crontab.  If you have added it to a users crontab, leave out the "ownername" bit.

That said, I wonder if this is a good way of doing things.  A totally different approach might be to simply remove all files older then a given age on a regular basis - you can do this with a 1 liner from crontab like

```
02 04 * * *     username     find /data/spam -ctime +15 -exec rm {} +
```

Which will look for all files older then 14 days in /data/spam and delete them.